# CORS for Azure Function in a Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, api, cors, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

Azure Functions allow [configuring CORS policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#cors) in a Function App. But how do we do the same for a [Function created in a Azure Static Web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=vanilla-javascript).

The Static Web App UI doesn't have a feature to configure CORS (screenshot below).

[image: Azure SWA - Functions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to separately setup CORS,  When you invoke a Function endpoint from a static page in an Azure Static Web Apps site, all the **`CORS settings`** are set up for you by default.

If you want to access the API within Azure static web app from an external endpoint, which is not supported as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/108).